# How to train BERT model with SQUAD 2.0 in Cloud TPU v2?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

Disclaimer: I am very new to Neural Network and Tensorflow.

I am trying to create a QA application where user asks a question and the application gives the answer. Most of the traditional methods I tried did not work or is not accurate enough or requires manual intervention. I was researching about unsupervised QA application, that is when I came across [BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert).

[BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert) as google claims is state of the art neural network model and achieved highest score in leader board for Squad 2.0. I wish to use this model for my application and test it's performance.

I have created a Windows 2012 Datacenter edition Virtual Machine in [Compute Engine.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstarts) I have created Cloud TPU using [**ctpu.**](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/ctpu-reference)

I have the [BERT large uncased model](https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2019_05_30/wwm_uncased_L-24_H-1024_A-16.zip) in Cloud Storage.

How do I train the BERT large uncased model with [SQUAD 2.0](https://github.com/google-research/bert#squad-20)?

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong, I have the understanding that Cloud TPU is just a device like CPU or GPU. However if you read [this](https://github.com/google-research/bert#squad-20), they are explaining like Cloud TPU is a virtual machine ("On Cloud TPU you can run with BERT-Large as...").

Where do I run [run_squad.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_squad.py) as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert#squad-20)?

```
python run_squad.py \
  --vocab_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/vocab.txt \
  --bert_config_file=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_config.json \
  --init_checkpoint=$BERT_LARGE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
  --do_train=True \
  --train_file=$SQUAD_DIR/train-v2.0.json \
  --do_predict=True \
  --predict_file=$SQUAD_DIR/dev-v2.0.json \
  --train_batch_size=24 \
  --learning_rate=3e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs=2.0 \
  --max_seq_length=384 \
  --doc_stride=128 \
  --output_dir=gs://some_bucket/squad_large/ \
  --use_tpu=True \
  --tpu_name=$TPU_NAME \
  --version_2_with_negative=True
```

How to access the the storage bucket files from Virtual Machine for this argument `vocab_file`?

Is the external IP address the value for `$TPU_NAME` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

So TPUs currently only read from GCS. The model that you've downloaded should be uploaded to another GCS bucket of your own creation. That's how the TPU will access `vocab_file` and other files.

Comment: How do I say in VM that this gs://example is the bucket I am trying to access? I tried to do that by creating a environment variable with value as 'gs://example'. It threw an error.

Comment: You should be trying to access the buckets that are defined by the environment variables. If you go here, https://github.com/google-research/bert, you should see that you are required to do `export BERT_BASE_DIR=gs://bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12` for example, if you are trying to use the base model.